# Perturbation theory : quadratic external field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, s-matrix-theory, wick-theorem

I'm trying to derive the explicit form of S-matrix of an interaction Hamiltonian

$$H' = \frac{1}{2} \lambda \left[ \int d^3 x \rho({\vec x}) \phi({\vec x}, t)\right]^2\tag{1}$$

Even though the interaction term is quadratic in the fields, I see that there are only two possible connected diagrams, just like for the interaction

$$H' = \lambda \int d^3 x \rho(x) \phi(x)\tag{2}$$

Except that, for $(1)$, the external field is time independent. So I must assume that the external field in $(1)$ is turned off adiabatic at some point in the past and future.

Therefore, my question is:

If I assume the external field in $(1)$ is time-dependent and goes to zero at light-like infinity, is the S-matrix for $(1)$ the same as that of $(2)$?

Also, when calculating matrix elements like below, which is scattering between one particle states, 
$$\langle {\vec k}' \vert S-1 \vert {\vec k} \rangle$$
which connected Wick diagrams should I consider for summing up?

Comment: Which part do you think it is a typo? I thought you were talking about the integration measure.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about that. No typo left that I can see.